# Linq query with multiple left outer joins fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am building an application where a user can post questions and upvote/downvote other people's questions. I have three tables in my mssql database - `Questions`, `Users`, and `QuestionVotes`.

The `Questions` table has columns `Id`, `AuthorId`, `Title`, `Content`, `Upvotes`, `Replies`.

The `Users` table has columns `Id`, `AuthorizationId`, `FirstName`, `LastName`.

The `QuestionVotes` table has columns `Id`, `QuestionId`, `UserId`, `Upvote`, `Downvote`. - an entry in this table indicates whether the user given by `UserId` has upvoted or downvoted the question given by `QuestionId`.

When a user logs in to the application, they should be able to see a list of questions posted by themselves and others, some author information for each question, as well as whether the current user has previously upvoted/downvoted the question. To get this information, I have the following function:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<QuestionWithAuthorInfo>> GetAllQuestionsWithAuthorInfo(long? currentUserId)
{
    var query = from question in Context.Set<Question>()
                join user in Context.Set<User>()
                on question.AuthorId equals user.Id into us
                from u in us.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join vote in Context.Set<QuestionVote>()
                on question.Id equals vote.QuestionId into vs
                from v in vs.Where(k =>currentUserId != null && k.UserId == currentUserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new QuestionWithAuthorInfo
                {
                    Id = question.Id,
                    Title = question.Title,
                    Content = question.Content,
                    Upvotes = question.Upvotes,
                    Replies = question.Replies,
                    Author = u == null ? null : new AuthorInfo
                    {
                        Id = u.Id,
                        FirstName = u.FirstName,
                        LastName = u.LastName
                    },
                    UserUpvoted = v == null ? false : v.Upvote,
                    UserDownvoted = v == null ? false : v.Downvote
                };
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

It is possible for `currentUserId` to be null - this is when the current user has not yet posted any questions or upvoted any questions. The desired outcome in this situation is for both `UserUpvoted` and `UserDownvoted` in the result to be `false`.

The query fails however with the following error message:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Question>
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<User>
            .AsQueryable(), 
        inner: question => question.AuthorId, 
        outerKeySelector: user => (Nullable<long>)user.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: (question, u) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = new { 
                question = question, 
                us = us
             }, 
            u = u
         })
    .GroupJoin(
        outer: DbSet<QuestionVote>, 
        inner: <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.question.Id, 
        outerKeySelector: vote => vote.QuestionId, 
        innerKeySelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier1, vs) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier1, 
            vs = vs
         })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at API.Repositories.Concrete.QuestionRepository.<GetAllQuestionsWithAuthorInfo>d__4.MoveNext()
```

How might I go about fixing this issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: I also tried 
`on new { p1 = question.Id, p2 = currentUserId } equals new { p1 = vote.QuestionId, p2 = (long?)vote.UserId} into vs
from v in vs.DefaultIfEmpty()`
but this is giving me the error "'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.'" I am unsure how to proceed....

Comment: Anyone? :( really struggling with this